# How to assign ViewData as source for WebGrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, razor-grid

In mvc4 i am getting Sample table value by ViewData in controller action.How can i pass that ViewData as source for WebGrid.

```
ViewData["SampleList"] = new List<Sample>(db.roles);
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
ViewBag.SampleList = new List<Sample>(db.roles);  

  var grid = new WebGrid(ViewBag.SampleList);
        @grid.GetHtml();
```

Comment: If i did like this, var grid = new WebGrid(ViewData["SampleList"]); it shows an invalid arguments error message.

Comment: @user2285613 i just update my code. Use `ViewBag` instead of `ViewData`.